# How to determine free memory in Mono/C# in Linux (without external DLL)

Tags: c#, linux, memory, mono

I'm able to read available memory using extern c function to a sys/sysinfo reading.
How ever I want to do this using mono's class (can't find relevant function in Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall), and I cannot use PerformanceCounter with "Available MBytes" as it is not implemented in mono..

Ubuntu/Mono 4.1.0

Any idea how to read free RAM in C#/Mono/Linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use sysinfo after all.  Polling each X seconds in a separate waiting thread.

And nice -15 is always nice to use.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a shell command from Mono with something like `free -m`

Comment: it is costly.. I saw mono has Unix.Native class which I can use for other needs. I need to trigger mem pressure and polling each second using shell command might slow the app dramatically..